# How can I show a string until the given condition valid, but no longer (console app)

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm making a console adventure game for practice and I need to display a text when my character close to an object (at adjacent position). This string must be displayed until the character close to the object, but if it step further the text need to gone.

I tried this:

```
        if (field[ver, hor + 1] == '█')
        {
            notice_detection = "DETECTION: '█' (right)";

            Console.SetCursorPosition(37, 0);
            Console.Write(notice_detection);
         }
         else
         {
            if (notice_detection != null)
            {
                notice_detection = "                      ";

                Console.SetCursorPosition(37, 0);
                Console.Write(notice_detection);
            }
        }
```

It's working but not too elegant. I'm sure a better solution exist.

My first try was to put 'notice_detection.Remove(0)' into else, but its didn't remove the already displayed string (by the way, why it's happened?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Remove()` method on strings returns a new string containing the remaining characters that are not removed starting from the given index. Calling it with `0` means that it removes everything from index `0` and returns the remaining, an empty string. If you write an empty string to the console, that looks like it does not did anything.

You can also replace your *whitespacing* hard coded string with a dynamic sized one filled with whitespaces like this:

```
var clearChars = new string(' ', notice_detection.Length);
Console.SetCursorPosition(37, 0);
Console.Write(clearChars);
```

Comment: FYI: Probably better to use _Console.BufferWidth_, as this would not require a dependency/knowledge of the string previously printed on the line, i.e.: `var startPos = 37; var clearChars = new string(' ', Console.BufferWidth - startPos);`